# Is my proof correct for: $\sqrt[7]{7!} < \sqrt[8]{8!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I have to show that

$$\sqrt[7]{7!} < \sqrt[8]{8!}$$

and I did the following steps

\begin{align}
 \sqrt[7]{7!} &< \sqrt[8]{8!} \\
 (7!)^{(1/7)} &< (8!)^{(1/8)} \\
 (7!)^{(1/7)} - (8!)^{(1/8)} &< 0 \\
 (7!)^{(8/56)} - (8!)^{7/56} &< 0 \\
 (8!)^{7/56} \left(\left( \frac{7!}{8!} \right)^{(1/56)} - 1\right) &< 0 \\
 \left(\frac{7!}{8!}\right)^{(1/56)} - 1 &< 0 \\
 \left(\frac{7!}{8!}\right)^{(1/56)} &< 1 \\
 \left(\left(\frac{7!}{8!}\right)^{(1/56)}\right)^{56} &< 1^{56} \\
 \frac{7!}{8!} < 1 \\
 \frac{1}{8} < 1 \\
\end{align}

Did I do this properly? Is this way the best way or is there another much easier way?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but perhaps a bit elaborate.

How about:

\begin{align}
&&\sqrt[7]{7!} &< \sqrt[8]{8!}\\
\iff&&(7!)^8 &< (8!)^7\\
\iff&&(7!)^7 7! &< (8\cdot 7!)^7\\
\iff&&7! &< 8^7
\end{align}

Comment: Beat me to it. Well done.

Comment: I'm slightly confused about your second step. How did you arrive at that? Did you just raise both sides to the power of the other term?

Comment: @gekkostate I raised both sides to the $56$th power (which amounts to what you wrote, as $7$ and $8$ are coprime).

Comment: ohh I see. Ya, I noticed they were coprime too but I didn't come to the same conclusion as you `:)`. This is very clever. Thanks!

Comment: @gekkostate Just remember the following rule for working with roots: try to get rid of them. :) It works surprisingly often.

Comment: Is his proof correct? Isn't there a mistake when he takes the 8! to the power of thing outside of the thing? Certainly the fact that you have 7!<8^7 and he gets 7!<8! makes me think there is a problem somewhere... Though of course this does demonstrate why getting rid of the roots is such a good idea because they confuse things. :)